# Peach trees stopped producing

Tags: diagnosis, fruit-trees, peaches

I have 2 peach trees , approximately 11-12 years old and after 8-9 years of great fruit production this year both trees just stopped producing
Not a single flower and or fruit.
Any suggestions?

Comment: There are farmer techniques that include whipping a tree, root pruning with a spade, or slightly scoring the trunk (not all the way around!) to wake it up if it's not otherwise sick.

Comment: Hows the leaf growth, perhaps a photo will help

Comment: And what was the weather like when they should have flowered, or shortly before that?

Answer (score 1):

Lots of orchards in my area got hit with untimely freezes and lost the entire year's production - no flowers means no fruit, and a freeze at the wrong time means no flowers.

I had a hardy apricot outright killed (no flowers, no leaves) without ever hitting temperatures below its "hardiness zone" - but there were some wild gyrations over the winter from very cold to quite warm. Not even a sucker from the rootstock, and it was happy last year.